# D3.js "Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute" for moving average

Tags: javascript, d3.js, average

I am trying to create a moving average over the rest of the chart.  I am trying to do something similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/plmrry/ktLtN/).
However, for my data points I continuously get the error:

"Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="M1.2121212121212122,NaNL1.4141414141414141,NaNC1.6161616161616161,NaN,2.0202020202020203,NaN,2.4242424..."

I believe it is because my data isn't formatted correctly, but I don't know how to modify the function to work with my data. My data currently looks like:

```
var data = [ {"x": 1, "y": 113},
{"x": 6, "y": 38},
{"x": 11, "y": 108},
{"x": 16, "y": 245},
{"x": 21, "y": 155},
{"x": 26, "y": 234},
...
```

Thanks

Comment: If your data is not too long, can you include it all in question? Or better yet, create a code snippet or jsfiddle that reproduces your problem.

Comment: It is 100 data points, so...

Comment: var data = [ {"x": 1, "y": 113},
 {"x": 6, "y": 38},
 {"x": 11, "y": 108},
 {"x": 16, "y": 245},
 {"x": 21, "y": 155},
 {"x": 26, "y": 234},
 {"x": 31, "y": 64},
 {"x": 36, "y": 154},
 {"x": 41, "y": 70},
 {"x": 46, "y": 258},
 {"x": 51, "y": 150},
 {"x": 56, "y": 78},
 {"x": 61, "y": 192},
 {"x": 66, "y": 120},
 {"x": 71, "y": 252},
 {"x": 76, "y": 131},
 {"x": 81, "y": 137},
 {"x": 86, "y": 269},
 {"x": 91, "y": 217},
 {"x": 96, "y": 122},
 {"x": 101, "y": 90},
 {"x": 106, "y": 177},
 {"x": 111, "y": 166},
 {"x": 116, "y": 46},
 {"x": 121, "y": 37},
 {"x": 126, "y": 125},
 {"x": 131,

Comment: Thats the max allowed

Comment: You can edit the question instead (and remove these comments). If your data is all numbers, then something in your function that calculates the average is wrong since something produces those `NaN`s. We'll need to see more of your code.

Comment: Here, I posted a JsFiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/surfaspen/yz87b53d/

Comment: Not sure but I was creating 2 lines hence my "y" value was an array of 2 numbers i.e 

var data = [{x: 'Jan', y: [8, 4]},{x: 'Feb', y: [4, undefined]}];

 out of which if anyone is undefined, I was getting same error. Solved it by setting undefined to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just map your *[{x1,y1}, {x2,y2}, ... {xN,yN}]* pairs to a *[y1, y2, ... yN]* series, which is what that moving average function expects:

```
movingAverageLine(data.map(function(d) { return d.y; }))
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure how I could do this until I saw @ekuusela's answer

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yz87b53d/3/

You should accept [meetamit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29995278/1630906) since that essentially was the issue.

```
movingAverageLine(data.map(function(d) { return d.y; }))
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I get how the function works now.  I didn't take enough time see that I had to send the y values to the function.  I'm just starting to mess around with D3.js.

Comment: I am now having a problem when trying to change the "x-step" value.  It works at 5, but when editing it the scale of the y values changes and wont fit the data.

Comment: Yeah I mistakenly applied that variable as the moving average parameter as well. I've now separated those two values and updated the fiddle. Note that this also stops working if your points are defined at different intervals of x than 5. You should consider defining your points without the x coordinate or you'll need to adjust the moving average calculation.

Comment: I realized that the moving count needed to be separate.  I think I will have to include an x coordinate because I'm trying to use cycling data from the [Strava API](http://strava.github.io/api/v3/streams/#activity).  The data from it might be taken at a constant rate, so in that case I could remove the x-coordinate.